# Swift if statement not returning value

Tags: macos, swift, if-statement

In the block of Code below, `String(quakeTsunamiWarning)` isn't returning with any response, and is giving the error `Use of Unresolved Identifier 'quakeTsunamiWarning'`

I'd like to apologise in advance if something is obviously wrong or blatantly obvious, but i'm still rather new when it comes to Programming with Swift. (Going off free tutorials I can find on Google here, as I don't have the funds to pay for a course or paid tutorial)

```
var quakeTsunami = 0

func newQuake() -> Void {
    if quakeTsunami == 0 {
        var quakeTsunamiWarning = "False"
    } else if quakeTsunami == 1 {
        var quakeTsunamiWarning = "True"
    } else {
        var quakeTsunamiWarning = "N/A"
    }

    println(String(quakeTsunamiWarning))
}
```

I've removed all the other code from the example, for sake of keeping this post relatively small, but here's a link to a gist if you want the full document. https://gist.github.com/kurisubrooks/0ba9f7547ee960657dec

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As for not affording a course or tutorial, have you read through Apple's free iBook?

Comment: I came across it on Google, but i'm not a very good reader. I'll have to look into it again though, thanks!

Comment: You can begin with the very condensed tour at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html if you prefer to learn from code, but I still recommend reading through the book as it explains everything in more depth. Note that the new version, Swift 2, is coming soon so some things will also change if you are still using Swift 1.x (as you seem to be, based on `println`, which is now `print`).

Comment: Oh interesting, I have to look into the changes. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three separate `quakeTsunamiWarning` variables, each only visible inside the innermost containing `{}`. Move it outside the `if`/`else` structure:

```
var quakeTsunamiWarning: String
if quakeTsunami == 0 {
    quakeTsunamiWarning = "False"
} …
```

And you don't need to convert it to `String` since it already is a `String`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So as an example, what could I do to fix this?

Comment: @KurisuBrooks Glad it helped, although I would encourage you to work through Apple's (free) book The Swift Programming Language, trying out things in a Playground as you read, this is quite basic stuff. (Also, if this answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it. =)

Comment: I marked it as accepted but it said I had to wait 10 minutes, but I just did it. Thanks so much for your help! I'll look into that book you specified.